# Android, Server, Database Application

Tags: android, database

i want to write an app which gets it's Data from a Database over the Internet! So my question is which Technologies do i need in order to implement this app. I have quite good experience in Android but Im not sure do i need an Application server which handle s the database on the server side? Or is there a function in the database which allows the android client to retrieve the data

and how do i get the Data from the database which is on the server so your help may be very appreciated.
Do i need a server side Application (which technology do i use jboss, tomcat etc.)
Database
communication technology to get the data from the database?
Does the data from the database is sent via xml or other?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: there is some way,like write an script that handle the request come from your app, another solution is use http://jtds.sourceforge.net/ to connect to server db,if you want good security better use server side script

Comment: with script you mean php or so but how do i create a java based programm, do i need an application server for the script or a webservice? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805240/connecting-to-external-database-android-application

Answer (score 1):

The questions you're asking would require a lengthy conversation to sufficiently answer, but hopefully I can get you pointed in the right direction. :)

For starters, you'll need some sort of web application/service set up that will allow you to communicate with a database. I've not heard of anyone directly connecting to a remote database via a mobile client. It's generally not desired.

99.99% of time, you'll communicate with the database through a web application. You'll make particular API calls to the server which in turn modify the database. You might try googling RESTful web services architecture. The web layer options are plenty... PHP, Rails, Django, Grails, the common Spring + Hibernate stack, Node.js, Go, etc. Your decision for this will largely influence what actual server technology you end up going with (Tomcat, JBoss, etc.). If you're a Java guy and want to stick with that stack, I'd recommend taking a look at Grails. If you're open to new platforms and languages, Ruby on Rails, Django (Python), Node.js (Javascript), and Revel (Go lang) would all be viable choices.

I suggest passing the data back and forth to the server using [JSON](http://json.org/example.html). It's what most people are using these days. Another option would be XML.

Hopefully that helps somewhat. Entire classes could be taught on the question you just asked :).