# Web App Database vs Mobile App Data base

Tags: android

I have created a Web Application for inventory management system and I have used SQLserver 2005 as my supporting Database. 
Now I need to create a similar application using Android.

My Questions are:
1.) Can I use the same Database for creating an android application or should I modify the database to fit the mobile platform.

2.) If I can use the above Database how is that I provide connectivity between android application and Sqlserver. Is Web service the only way out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes you would need a web service layer in between your android and database layer.

Comment: We do it with 2 DB's one on the net other in the device and when there is network available we sync the two databases.

Comment: The natively supported database engine for Android apps is SQLite. Whether or not you can use the same database really depends on your database definition, but since SQLite features only a subset of SQL it's likely you'll have to make some alterations. If you do go down the SQLite road, be aware that foreign key constraints need to be explicitly enabled to be enforced (`pragma foreign_keys=on`)

Comment: Thanks a lot @ 2-Stoker, but this raises another question in my mind. Will the same Database created for Web app will work fine on adding a web service layer in between with the android app or should I be creating a all together new database compatible with android?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805240/connecting-to-external-database-android-application